# How will the prototype chain break?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am  trying to learn inheritance in JavaScript .This article on  [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#Different_ways_to_create_objects_and_the_resulting_prototype_chain) explains how prototype chain works.

```
let f = function () {
   this.a = 1;
   this.b = 2;
}
let o = new f(); // {a: 1, b: 2}


f.prototype.b = 3;
f.prototype.c = 4;
```

there is comment which says

```
// do not set the prototype f.prototype = {b:3,c:4}; this will break the prototype chain
```

How will this break chain ? . My guess is that because we are overwriting prototype object of constructor function so all other reference of *upward chain* is lost .But we could set object to f.prototype using **Object.create(someobject)** and this don't break the chain.

Comment: ***My guess is that because we are overwriting prototype object of constructor function so all other reference of upward chain is lost***.  Not quite.  It's not that upward chain reference is lost.  It's that you replaced the current prototype so anything else that was already on the prototype is now lost.  It's the same as doing `let x = {a: 1}` and then doing `x = {b: 2}`.  You replaced the entire object that was assigned to `x` with a different object so when you do `console.log(x)`, there would be no `a` property on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f.prototype = Object.create(someobject);
```

properties and method  of someobject will be availble in f.protoype object. And hence,all instances of f will have those methods and properties available  to them.

**Why it won't break chain ?**

**Object.create()** directly constructs an object based on (prototype) argument provided. the argument itself (may)  have all references available through its [[prototype]] property